# How to create next page automatically in html2pdf with mysql

Tags: html, mysql, pdf, html2pdf, pdf-conversion

I use php to convert htmle2pdf with mysql, I want html2pdf with mysql next page aftrer totalrows=5
Please help me so that some how i make a page break in the pdf file after every 5 rows automatically go to next page with the header and footer!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can surround every 5 rows with `<page>` tag.